# Oracle Driver along with packaged war file

Tags: hibernate, oracle11g, jboss6.x

My webapplication packaged as .war file has below maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Dependency is getting resolved properly during maven build and packaged .war contains ojdbc6 artifact in its /lib directory. However application throws an exception like below

15:00:00,409 WARN  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] Could not obtain connection to query metadata: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found
for jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.253.XX.165:1555/XXXX
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602) [:1.6.0_31]
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154) [:1.6.0_31]
        at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133) [:3.6.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:114) [:3.6.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2833) [:3.6.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2829) [:3.6.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1840) [:3.6.0.Final]

Works fine when ojdbc6.jar manually placed in default/lib folder of JBoss.

Do I have to mention dependency to the oracle driver module in the manifest entry of the WAR? How to do so?

Comment: by "/lib directory", you mean WEB-INF/lib, right? Do you have any code or setting file that tries to load the Oracle driver class by name (because if it depends on auto-registration, that may not work with the repackaged jar)?

Comment: Yes you are right. I put the driver jar into WEB-INF/lib. However JBoss not able load it from WEB-INF/lib. Do I have to register the jar in any manifest file?

Comment: I don't know if that is the best solution, but I'd try a `Class.forName` with the Oracle driver in the startup code of your app.